# Adding a shim to a static method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, shim

I've got some legacy code to add unit testing to. I can add shims where necessary to classes that need instanciating, but some of the code uses static classes. I can't add a shim properly.

for example (simplified for clarity):

```
public static class DBHelper
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<Run> GetRuns()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Run> retval = new ObservableCollection<Run>();

            using (AriaEntities DBC = new AriaEntities())
            {
                var res = DBC.Runs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Run_Number).Take(100).ToList();

                retval = new ObservableCollection<Run>(res);
            }

            return retval;
        }
    }
```

I want to shim this method. if it was non static, I'd use:

```
 using (ShimsContext.Create())
 {
      ShimDBHelper.AllInstances.GetRuns = (i) => { return FakeRunList(); };

      ...
 }
```

But with a static I get "'DBHelper': static types cannot be used as parameters". If I remove the parameter, I get told that the delegate doesn't take 0 arguments.

Whats the syntax for a static class, if there is one?

Comment: While I am no expert on this particular area, if you are stuck with the static class why not try with the `AriaEntities` instance within the static class?

Comment: `ShimDBHelper` should have the `GetRuns` property that you can assign?